# Is there a way to use babelJS on js function with yield on the fly?

Tags: javascript, yield, babeljs

I need to use yield action on older browsers that doesnt support it,
I have understood that babelJS contains support for such a transition.
the thing is that I need this transition to be performed client-side on the fly as my app generates javascript on the fly.
I will need something like a js function to call on a given code(can be string or evaluated code) that will parse it to ES5 code on the fly?
is there a way or some tutorial that will help me do so?

thanks for the helpers.

Comment: You [can](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/) do it, but probably shouldn't ... what's your use case?

Comment: What do you mean by "transition"?

Comment: The idea is that the user will select actions to perform - send text to host send enter to host etc, those actions can be done inside loops and if statements(so it cannot be done in a queue - it has logic that can be changed from user to user), the idea is to wait after specific actions for the host to replay with data, the yield functionality gave me a great solution for this issue in the latest browsers, i encountered babelJs when started looking for solutions in IE9 & IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/ you can compile with Babel client-side. Mind the warning there though, that it is not intended for serious use.

Comment: first of all thanks, My product is supported by IE9 and IE10 as well so i need to find a solution for the yield section, and is there a tutorial more than this page for using the browser.js ? what are the prerequisites for my web app and stuff like that?

Comment: Babel supports IE9+. Since it's such a rare use case, you need to try it yourself. There don't seem to be any prerequisites. The "try it out" section on that site is made using the browser-side script, it seems.